# About Google Cloud Deploy by gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to do Blue/Green Deployment in GCP on VM instances like Code Deploy in AWS?
If so, which GCP managed service should I use?

I want to do Blue/Green Deploy using a managed service like Code Deploy like AWS in GCP.

Comment: Cloud Deploy is based on Skaffold and you can only deploy on Cloud Run or GKE. VM Instances are not managed by Cloud Deploy. You can perform blue/green on VM Instances "manually" with different instance template, load balancer routing and traffic splitting.